Multiple function Parameters Without Declaration?
I want to have a function with infinite parameters but I don't want to declare them How do I do this?
function func(){
   for(let i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
      console.log(param[i]);
   }
}



Note that the more modern way to do it is shown in the second answer down – function render(...foo) { /* code */ }, where foo will be an array.

@Ry- Never knew that. Thanl you.

If you have a new question, please ask a new question – it’ll be much more visible.

@Ry- not allowed it also said edit this one
